# Sequentialfs using MATLAB Tables

Tags: matlab, feature-selection, matlab-table

I previously used nothing but large matrices as arguments within the `sequentialfs` function within MATLAB. I have a newly upgraded MATLAB which contains the `Table` data type -- very handy. I attempted to rework a script which performs sequential feature selection utilizing the table set but have ran into trouble.

```
normfmat = ngmft(:,4:end-1); % ngmft is previously loaded data table
y = gmft(:,2); % categorical variable with two classes

c = cvpartition(y,'k',10); % first error produced here

fun = @(trainData,trainClass,testData,testClass)...
  (sum(~strcmp(testClass,predict(ClassificationKNN.fit(trainData,trainClass,'NumNeighbors',1),testData))));

[fs,history] = sequentialfs(fun,X,y,'cv',c) % second error here
```

The first error produced is

> Error using statslib.internal.grp2idx (line 44)
>   You cannot subscript a table using only one subscript. Table subscripting >requires both row and variable subscripts.
>
> Error in grp2idx (line 28)
>   [varargout{1:nargout}] = statslib.internal.grp2idx(s);
>
> Error in cvpartition (line 164)
>   cv.Group = grp2idx(N);
>
> Error in script (line 32)
>   c = cvpartition(group,'k',10);

This error goes away if I convert the `classlab` to a categorical array, but then a second error is produced at the `sequentialfs` call:

> Error using sequentialfs (line 345)
>   All input arguments must be tables.

So my question is, essentially, how does one utilize tables with the sequential feature selection process? In particular, the first error confuses me because I am feeding it a table with specified indices. For the second error, `cvpartition` returns a cvpartition object and `y` has been converted to a categorical array. The first was never a table and in the second I appear to be locked into due to the first error generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `()` indexing on a `table` returns a subset of the table but it's *still* a table and therefore is going to result in errors if you try to pass it to functions which expect a numeric array.

If you simply want the *values* from the table, you'll want to use `{}` indexing instead.

```
t = table([1 2 3].', [4 5 6].');

%       Var1    Var2
%       ____    ____
%   
%       1       4   
%       2       5   
%       3       6   

class(t(1,:))

%   table

disp(t(1,:))

%   Var1    Var2
%   ____    ____
%
%   1       4   

class(t{1,:})

%   double

disp(t{1,:})

%   1     4
```

[More information on access data within a table](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html)

So looking back at your specific example, you likely want to pass an *array* (not a table) to `cvpartition` to prevent the first error

```
c = cvpartition(gmft{:,2});
```

For the call to `sequentialfs`, you haven't shown us what `X` is but I would assume it's a table. If you fix that first error, the `sequentialfs` call shouldn't complain since both `y` and `X` would be tables.

Comment: Oddly enough, I still get that second error. It won't accept x and y as tables in my code. However, you layout very clearly what it is I was doing wrong for the first error and that same approach (outputting arrays) to the sequentialfs call works around the other problem. It is simple enough to reference back to the original table with the sequential fs output to identify the feature by name. If you have any idea what might cause sequentialfs to complain (with both x and  y being tables) I'm all ears, but otherwise I consider this basically solved.